# Ros on anything else than ubuntu: how?

Tags: ros, installation, build-from-source, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I used Ros a while ago for Univ.
Now I'd like to test it in a work environment and where there is a mix of CentOS and Debian.
I can't seem to find any updated information about building from source.
The latest I can find is Electric on Debian.

What's the situation nowadays?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222483/ros-on-anything-else-than-ubuntu:-how?/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source
http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-14**:
Note that you may run into issues if you follow the default (Ubuntu) from-source installation instructions on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian)?

You might also be interested in [DebianScience/Robotics/ROS](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Robotics/ROS), but it's not complete yet, afaik.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1